# Есть ли практическая разница между использованием непрозрачного указателя и указателя на void?

Tags: c++, c, void, pimpl

Подскажите, пожалуйста, если рассматривать реализацию `API` библиотеки (в `C` стиле), то есть ли какая-нибудь разница (в практическом смысле) между непрозрачным указателем и указателем на `void`?

Comment: непонятно, а как предполагается работать с этим указателем? под _непрозрачным указателем_ я так понял, понимается typedef на обычный указатель.

Comment: @Arenoros, нет, под непрозрачным указателем я имею в виду неполный тип. Например, объявленная, но неопределенная структура. Формально, `void` тоже является неполным типом, но его не рассматриваем.

Comment: Указатель на void можно использовать в качестве непрозрачного.

Comment: в практическом смысле удобнее, т.к. в экспортной функции ты видишь не `void* data`, а `OpaquePtr* data`, такая самодокументация

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В случае непрозрачных указателей, указатели на физически разные сущности будут иметь разный тип. Наличие типов позволяет: диагностировать некоторые типы ошибок на стадии компиляции; упростить документирование; упростить упростить написание C++ оберток (вокруг указаетлей и функций); ... В широком смысле, мы получаем преимущества статически типизируемого языка над динамически типизируемым.

Сравните:

```
  typedef void* HTexture;
  typedef void* HTransformation;
  void transformTexture( HTexture texture, HTransformation transformation);


  struct Texture; 
  typedef Texture* HTexture;
  struct Transformation;
  typedef Transformation* HTransformation;
  void transformTexture( HTexture , HTransformation );
```

В случае непрозрачных указателей компилятор сможет выдать сообщение об ошибке, если вы перепутаете аргументы, а случае `void*` - нет.

Некоторые (устаревшие) средства разработки, выдают всплывающие подсказки по функциям с учетом подстановки всех typedef, т.е. подскажут пользователю `transformTexture(void*, void*)` и он будет вынужден, каждый раз, смотреть документацию, вместо использования подсказок.

При применении функционального подхода, т.е., например, при автоматическом генерировании функций по прототипу:

```
template< typename FunctionPtr >
FunctionPtr applayLogger( FunctionPtr );
auto loggedTransformTexture = applayLogger( &transformTexture );
```

В подсказках к loggedTransformTexture информация о типах, в лучшем случае, будет приведена с учетом подстановки typedef, а имена аргументов будут потеряны. В тоже время информации о типах может быть достаточно.

При применении идеомы RAII, написание C++ оберток существенно упростится именно в случае отдельный типов. (Поскольку мы сможем автоматически вывести нужную функуию деструкции на основании типа, а не отслеживать историю происходения указателя.)

И наконец, если пользователь захочет написать прегруженные фкункции, принимающие аргументы разных типов. То это возможно только в случае, если типы не тождественны друг другу.

Comment: *"В случае непрозрачных указателей компилятор сможет выдать сообщение об ошибке, если вы перепутаете аргументы, а случае void* - нет."* - сдается мне, что вы тут просто противопоставляете типизированные указатели указателям на void, хотя и те, и другие могут быть использованы в качестве непрозрачных.